# Is there a CSS Selector to select all first descendents of a given element?

Tags: css

```
<article>
 <header targetme!>
  <h1 don't target me></h1>
 </header>
 <p targetme! ></p>
 <p targetme! ></p>
 <div targetme!>
  <p don't target me></p>
 </div>
</article>
```

Is there a CSS selector (IE7 and up) that we can use to select only the first descendants of a given element (in this case, article) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators), `>`, which will select direct children only, along with the [universal selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#universal-selector), `*`, to match all elements:

```
article > * {
    /* Your styles */
}
```

Note that while IE7 does support the child combinator, IE6 does not.

Answer (score 1):

use the `>` to select first descendents/child elements of a selector

```
.selector > .childelementonlyselector
```

This applys to id selectors `#id`, tag selectors `div` and class selectors as in the example above `.class`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to select all direct descendants:

```
article > *
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `$('article').children();`

that should do what you want, see [**.children()**](http://api.jquery.com/children/) api reference.

Comment: The question is asking for CSS... not jQuery.